# Visual C++ perfect forwarding compile error

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, visual-studio-2017

Any reason why this does not compile in Visual Studio C++? I'm using Visual Studio 2017 15.7.1. It compiles in clang and g++:

```
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

struct Foo {
    Foo(int x) {}
    Foo(Foo const& b) {}
};

struct Bar {
    template <class... Args>
    Bar(Args&&... args)
        : foo(std::forward<Args>(args)...) {}

    Foo foo;
};

void test() {
    std::vector<Bar> v;
    v.emplace_back(123);
}
```

The error is `error C2664: 'Foo::Foo(const Foo &)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'Bar' to 'int'`

See https://godbolt.org/g/bKb34v

EDIT: I've submitted this issue here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/252470/perfect-forwarding-compiler-bug.html

Comment: It looks like a compiler bug, you should report this to MS

Comment: Confirmed with MSVS 15.6.6 and toolset v141. But it compiles with toolsets v140 and v140_xp

Comment: That's a pretty dismal bug

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is your bug, not MSVC's.

1. `Foo`'s copy constructor is not `noexcept` and it has no move constructor.
2. `Bar`'s implicitly declared move constructor is not `noexcept` either, because it needs to call the aforementioned copy constructor for the `Foo` data member.
3. `emplace_back` may reallocate, and since `Bar` appears copyable, that reallocation will copy the existing elements to preserve the strong exception safety guarantee.
4. This copying may be done, depending on the implementation, from a `const` or non-`const` `Bar` lvalue.
5. Your unconstrained constructor template hijacks copying from a non-const `Bar` lvalue.
6. Explosions and fireworks follow.

The fix is to constrain the constructor template so that it doesn't hijack. For example:

```
template <class... Args, 
          class = std::enable_if_t<std::is_constructible_v<Foo, Args...>>>
Bar(Args&&... args)
    : foo(std::forward<Args>(args)...) {}
```